# Syntax errors in WinCE C file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

I'm using `Visual Studio 2008`. I'm working on `AM335x WinCE7` BSP. I added a new library source code which involves header files from common folder. The issue I'm facing is that, when I compile that library code, I'm getting syntax error in a class in common folder header file. There is no possibility for syntax errors to occur in common codes. So, I doubt that some other issue might be causing this. 
I'm getting a warning regarding this, which I feel, leads to the error.

```
warning C4218: nonstandard extension used : must specify at least a storage class or a type
```

I used `pragma` to suppress the warning. But, though the warning was ignored, the error persists.

Please guide me regarding this as I don't have any idea about this. Also, if any other information is needed regarding this, please comment.

**EDIT1:**

Actually the code is huge. Please refer [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5aa8045-1936-4fe5-8b1a-1c31c3fd5baf/class-in-header-file-gets-error-c2061). I'm facing very similar issue. They have asked to add StdAfx.cpp and StdAfx.h files. But it is for VC++. So, I'm confused whether it conforms to wince C file also.

**EDIT2:**

I'm getting the following errors.

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CReg'
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
warning C4431: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C no longer supports default-int
warning C4218: nonstandard extension used : must specify at least a storage class or a type


class CSDIOControllerBase   -> C2061,C2059
{                           -> C2449
 // some code

};                          -> C2059

CSDIOControllerBase *CreateSDIOController();    -> C2143
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the code from the libraries that generates the warning?

Comment: @Lundin I have edited my post. Please check it out.

Comment: The code may be "huge", but the error message and the warning will specify a specific file and line of code.  You could post both the affected line (perhaps at least with its surrounding lines), and post the error message - not just the warning.  These messages are called "compiler diagnostics" for a reason!

Comment: The link you posted does not mention C4218, what makes you say that this issue as at all similar?

Comment: @Clifford The link mentions Syntax errors in 'class'. That's what is occuring in my code. The warning C2148, I think (I may not be right also), leads to these syntax errors. I have added the code anyways.

Comment: @Clifford Actually the piece of code I mentioned was from a `.h` file. It is included in `.c` file. I changed the file extension to `.cpp` file. It compiles. So, was it the real problem?

Comment: @Gomu: A "syntax error" is specific to the particular syntax, there is no reason to equate one syntax error cause with another from entirely different code.  It is a generic error type that simply means that "this code is not valid C++".

Comment: The compiler diagnostics include useful information such as filename and line numbers, but you have removed that information from the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to compile as C is in fact C++, and therefore requires C++ compilation.  You cannot include a C++ header directly in code compiled as C.

If you need to use the features provided by this header, the chances are that you will need to use C++ in any case.  So your own code will need to be C++ in nay case.